# Is there an item maniac in Alola?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

An [item maniac](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Item_maniac) is a person who will purchase certain items from the player at a higher price than what they would be sold for, like in 5th generation games. I own several [valuable items](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Valuable_item) and I want to sell them at the best price.

The description for the mushrooms suggests it:

> It's popular with a certain class of collectors and sought out by them.

Is there an item maniac in Pokemon Sun/Moon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Bulbapedia Item Maniac entry](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Item_maniac), it looks like these were only featured in Gen 5 (Unova) and have not been featured since.

> An item maniac (Japanese: どうぐマニア item maniac) is a person who will purchase certain items from the player at a higher price than what they would be sold for to a Poké Mart. Some items which cannot be sold to Poké Marts can be sold to item maniacs. **They appeared in Generation V.**

Additionally, in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187276-pokemon-sun/74594243?page=1), people have denied their existence.

> Are there any item maniacs?
>
> No

Another telling sign that these are absent in Sun and Moon is the fact that, while there is a [Serebii page for the B/W item collectors](http://www.serebii.net/blackwhite/collectors.shtml), there is not a page for them for S/M.

Comment: Bummer. I had that feeling...